# Handle server response in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, asp-classic

I have an asp page that loads a response " user=exists " everytime I try to update a database record (when of course the record already exists!)
How can I handle this response with AS3 in Flash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming you are using a URLLoader...

```
// Create a URLLoader to handle sending and loading 
loader = new URLLoader();

// add listeners
if (!loader.hasEventListener( Event.COMPLETE)) {
    loader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, handleResponse);
}

// send the data to the URL
loader.load(request);
```

and then the handleResponse function

```
private function handleResponse(e:Event):void{
    trace("Returned : " + new String(e.target.data));
}
```

e.target.data being the response,

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Can you please also mention what if the response is in an XML format like: <user>exists</user>?

Comment: then instead of `new String(e.target.data)` you could use `new XML(e.target.data)`